# Pass plain value to model Select2 angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

I use [select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) from angular-ui, everything works ok, but it passes to ng-model object and I need to get plain value

this is in controller

```
$scope.units = {
            createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
                if ($(data).filter(function() {
                    return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0; }).length===0) {
                    return {id:term, text:term};
                }
            },
            multiple: false,
            data: [{id: 0, text: 'kg'},{id: 1, text: 'ks'},{id: 2, text: 'm'}, {id: 3, text: 'h'}]
        };
```

and this in view

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="unit_name" ui-select2="units" ng-model="newItem.unit">
```

but result is {id: 0, text: 'kg'} and I would need only text from that object. I know that is is possible to get it with .val(), but I not able to use with angular... So how to format output? Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem, and i got solution by remove some line of code from the `select2-ui.js`.

Commnet following code in select2-ui.js

```
elm.bind("change", function(e) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   if (scope.$$phase || scope.$root.$$phase) {
      return;
   }
   scope.$apply(function() {
      controller.$setViewValue(
      convertToAngularModel(elm.select2('data')));
   });
});
```